# Laravel Code working on the Localhost but Fail on the server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a simple Ajax Jquery function that post an edited article data which is routed then to a controller

---

```
//Controller articleManagement
    function editArticle(){
        $a=$this->inputs;
        $response=DB::table('articles')
            ->where('id', $a["id"])
            ->update(array($a["column"] => $a["val"]));
        return $response;
    }
```

---

```
//routes.php
Route::post('/xarticle', "articleManagement@editArticle");
```

---

```
//ajax Jquery
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/xarticle",
                data: {
                    id:id,
                    val:eval("CKEDITOR.instances.content"+id+".getData()"),
                    column:"content"
                },
                success:function(data){
                    data=Number(data);
                    Boolean(data)?alertify.success("Data successfully updated."):alertify.error("Nothing was updated.");
                }
            });
```

The above Code works perfectly when I am in the localhost with all kinds of `val`. But in the production on the remote server it works in small values for example "Hello World" "bla bla bla bla bla" however it fails when I want to post an article and return a 404 not found page error.

This Error is showing up in laravel.log

```
[2014-12-26 23:20:07] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' 
Stack trace:
#0 /home/yahyouha/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(3238): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->abort(404)
#1 /home/yahyouha/html/app/routes.php(53): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('abort', Array)
#2 /home/yahyouha/html/app/routes.php(53): Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::abort(404)
#3 [internal function]: {closure}('xarticle')
#4 /home/yahyouha/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(5331): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#5 /home/yahyouha/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(4998): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 /home/yahyouha/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(4986): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 /home/yahyouha/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(715): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 /home/yahyouha/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(696): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 /home/yahyouha/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(7746): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#10 /home/yahyouha/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(8353): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#11 /home/yahyouha/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(8300): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#12 /home/yahyouha/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(10962): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#13 /home/yahyouha/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(657): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /home/yahyouha/public_html/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#15 {main} [] []
```

**EDIT**

I have noticed if I delete image code  and some other chars it starts working it might be some configurations from the apache to not accept special chars to post for preventing injecting?

Comment: have you ruled out bugs in the eval statement? I'd log this value for each request `eval("CKEDITOR.instances.content"+id+".getData()")`

Comment: @EruPenkman I have already passed this piece of code to console.log(); it was simply returning something similar to "<span> bla bla bla</span>"

Comment: @EruPenkman but when I don't enter any new line,",' the code works so i believe it something related with the fact the ajax post refuse to be sent because of presence of these characters. worth to mention that the code works perfectly on my localhost

Comment: updated my answer, i think you're right you should be able to get around that filter by encoding the html from js then decoding it in php

Answer (score 0):

I think you're correct that the server is filtering POST bodys that contain HTML, maybe using [mod_security rules](http://www.modsecurity.org/demo-deny-noescape.html). you can probably get around this by encoding the html fragments with

```
val: encodeURIComponent(htmlFragment)
```

in php you will have to decode it ( but maybe php does this for you automatically)

```
urldecode($a["val"])
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my id is simply a number why would it need any encoding ?

Comment: hmm your right, I think that post bodys don't even need encoding, must be a different issue

Comment: maybe someone has injected data so that it's not only a simple number any longer?

Comment: i think it is most likely something related with blocking the ajax request when i use simple <span> without " or ' it works . I just don't have any clue what it can be.

Comment: so you tried the encodeURIComponenet and that still gets blocked?

Comment: yep in fact the jquery ajax is automatically encoding it